# Introducing multiple lags of DV as IV in regression

Tags: regression, lags, dynamic-regression

Background - I have to estimate the impact of different promotional channels on the sales of a product. We don't have sales so technically it is order data at a zip level. Also, the product is highly seasonal with a cycle of 12 months. My teammate ran a marketing mix model and did not get good results so I am trying a different model - period to period change model (S_post (curr yr 6 mths aggregated) = S_pre (pre yr 6 mths aggregated) + Promotions (curr yr 6 mths aggregated)) to see if we can get some estimates.

Problem - Since the data is highly seasonal, I am using the sales from last season to control for base sales. If I try to introduce additional lag for immediate previous 6 months my promotion coefficients for some channels become negative. It is kind of the same problem which my teammate faced in the MMM.

Can you please help me understand what is exactly happening and if I can reason to have only one the seasonal lag. I understand that introducing lags of DV is not advised but in this industry previous sales are a big part and even though there is a risk of coefficient bias it can't be ignored.

Comment: Are you trying to do time series analysis?

Comment: Although the data is time series, I am aggregating it to run a cross sectional model. My teammate tried a time series Marketing Mix model but we didn't get any results with that.